# Nested ng-repeat with large amount of data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the following HTML code i am using nested `ng-repeat` directive

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="list in listItems">
      {{list.name}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list.items">
          {{item.val}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Input Data

```
 $scope.listItems = [
      {name:'name1',items:[{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'}]},
      {name:'name2',items:[{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'},{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'}]},
      {name:'name3',items:[{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'},{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'},{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'}]},
      {name:'name4',items:[{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'},{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'},{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'},{val:'item1'},{val:'item2'},{val:'item3'}]}
      ];
```

In real time , the number of values contained in items element is more than 5000. If I run this in IE8 I am getting script time out error.

How to avoid the script error?

I thought of displaying the partially in the screen but here 1 item can contain minimum of 1 val to maximum of around 10,000.

Please suggest any solution.

sample plunker

Please fine the sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Okf9lyY9zCYqT5sMD0S?p=preview)

Comment: Can u post ur error message? With all details of it

Comment: Is ur all ur data are in the client side? Or u have to call ur rest services on ever change? Is this problem ie8 only?

Comment: Error Message: Stop running this script?
A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.

Comment: I am getting the data from rest service but the error occurs only when i bind the data to scope element. In IE 8 only i am getting this error in all other browsers it is taking more time to render the page

Comment: When I run this plunker with IE8 emulator in IE11, I cannot reproduce the error

Comment: Plunker is just a sample data. If the number of items are more (more than 5000) i am getting this error. since i cannot give that much amount of data i gave sample data. Also you should run in ie 8 to replicate this issue. This is not re-producible in IE8 emulator in IE11.